# Регулярное выражение на выделение подстроки

Tags: preg_match, регулярные-выражения, php

У меня есть строка (относительный адрес) ../folder1/folder2/folder3
Как написать регулярное выражение для функции preg_match, чтоб получить строку /folder3,
или хотя бы просто folder3, т.е. последнюю папку? Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$filename - ваша строка.

1)

```
basename($filename) // Возвращает все, что после последнего слэша
```

2)

```
function getBasename($filename){ // Возвращает все, что после последнего слэша  
  $pos = strrpos($filename, '/');  
    if($pos===false) {  
      return false;  
  } else {  
    return substr($filename, $pos+1);  
  }  
}
```

Регулярки тут, имхо, излишни. :)

Comment: мммм даа. стормозил шушуть,) просто в моем случае basename() уже возвращала имя файла и это меня почемуто затормозило. но уже допер как "вынуть" и последний каталог. огромное спасибо!!! все получилось ))

Comment: @Alexof, не забываем галочку жать)

Comment: ок. я тут просто первый раз вопрос задал )))

Comment: Danke shoen. (Спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('#^.*/([^/]+)$#', $path, $match); // =)
```

А еще

```
$folder = end(explode('/', $path));
```

Comment: мне последнее нравится :)

Comment: почемуто не работает (( учу регулярки по книге, там почемуто ничего не сказано про знак #

Comment: Это, типа, delimeter, ограничитель. Им может быть любой символ, не используемый в регулярке. Обычно это слэш, но здесь он неудобный был.

После этого кода совпадения находятся в $match 

    print_r($match); // выведет массив

Comment: понятно. да за массив в курсе. спасибо большое.)